# SQL query on second table based on multiple response from first

Tags: sql

Here is a SQL query which fail if multiple values are returned by first-

```
SELECT     subject
FROM         a_batchcourse_subject AS s
WHERE     (batchcourse =
                          (SELECT     batchcourse
                          FROM          a_course_batchcourse AS b
                          WHERE      (course = 'Course 1')))
```

what is the right way to write this query where first query may return multiple values ?

Comment: is batchcourse of table a_course_batchcourse unique

Comment: if batchcourse is unique then try JOIN otherwise use IN

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JOIN` is much faster than `IN` clause

```
SELECT  s.subject
FROM    a_batchcourse_subject s 
        INNER JOIN a_course_batchcourse b
        on s.batchcourse = b.batchcourse
WHERE   (b.course = 'Course 1')
```

Comment: Here is the exact query which worked for me SELECT     s.subject
FROM         a_batchcourse_subject AS s INNER JOIN
                      a_course_batchcourse AS b ON s.batchcourse = b.batchcourse
WHERE     (b.course = 'Course 1')

Comment: @johntotetwoo join and in are two different thing and in is faster than join

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble perhaps you can read this article: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/940-SQL-Optimization-Case-Study-JOIN-Clause-vs-IN-Clause.htm .

Comment: inner join and in are two different things your query will return more than expected if b.batchcourse is not unique

Answer (score 5):

You want `IN` in sql not `=`

```
SELECT subject
FROM a_batchcourse_subject AS s
WHERE batchcourse IN
(SELECT batchcourse
FROM a_course_batchcourse AS b
WHERE course = 'Course 1')
```

Comment: Gee 16 second difference with mine :) this answer is correct @Tectrendz +1 for him and you